# Automate Jasmine Test in Gradle

Tags: javascript, testing, gradle, jasmine

In my case, I have a Java Web based in Gradle. In my web project I have files .js which I want to make unit testing using JASMINE. I need execute this test when the command "gradle build" is called.

if is posible, please, share with me very basic project to understand.

Extra: In an environment of continuous integration (like Jenkins Tool) is very important automate unit test.

Comment: What you need to do is to write a task that will execute the mentioned jasmine tests and configure task `build` to depend on the newly-created task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I'm not familiar with Jasmine

Firstly, I'd create a `sourceSet` for jasmine

```
sourceSets {
    jasmine {
        resources {
            srcDir "$webAppDirName"
            srcDir 'src/test/jasmine'
            include '**/*.js'
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I'd create a task to execute jasmine

```
task jasmineTest(type: Exec) {
    def outputDir = file("$buildDir/jasmine")

    // set the task inputs/outputs for up-to-date checking
    inputs.files sourceSets.jasmine 
    outputs.dir outputDir

    // configure the Exec task
    executable 'jasmine.exe'
    args ['-d', outputDir, '-f', sourceSets.jasmine.output.files.join(',')]
}
```

Then, attach your task to the `check` task

```
check.dependsOn jasmineTest
```